# Higher recursion theory and reverse mathematics: What is to $\Pi^1_1$-$CA_0$ as $RCA_0$ is to $ACA_0$?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory, reverse-math

There is an extremely rich and well-understood analogy between "recursively enumerable" and "$\Pi^1_1$" – indeed, this is the starting point of metarecursion theory, and $\alpha$-recursion theory in general (see Sacks' wonderful book [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813160253/https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422632)).

I'm interested in whether there is a straightforward reverse mathematical analogy to be made here, as well. Specifically, we usually think of $RCA_0$ and $ACA_0$ as "recursive comprehension" and "recursively enumerable comprehension," respectively; I'm wondering if there is a theory $T$ such that we can – in a similar way – think of $T$ as "metarecursive comprehension" and $\Pi^1_1$-$CA_0$ as "metarecursively enumerable comprehension."

A natural candidate for that theory might be $\Delta^1_1$-$CA_0$, but that's not quite right: in the metarecursive context, $\Delta^1_1$ corresponds to finite (since intuitively everything is relative to Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$). I've been thinking that the right $T$ here is $ATR_0$, but I don't really have any serious reason to back that up.

My instinct is that this is not really the right question – metarecursion theory doesn't live on $\omega$, it lives on $\omega_1^{CK}$, so the right thing to do is formulate a version of reverse math on $\omega_1^{CK}$ (in fact, Richard Shore [http://www.math.cornell.edu/~shore/papers/pdf/RMComp7.pdf](http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Eshore/papers/pdf/RMComp7.pdf) has already done this for cardinals, and I don't see anything preventing his work extending to arbitrary admissible ordinals – although his theorems might not, of course, since they may require more admissiblity than $\Sigma_1$). But I'm still holding out hope that there's something neat that can happen already on $\omega$.

(I've tagged "descriptive-set-theory" because of the deep connections between higher recursion theory and descriptive set theory, but if anyone feels that that's too much of a reach here, feel free to untag.)

Comment: Since metarecursive + bounded = metafinite, for subsets of $\omega$, $\Delta^1_1$ corresponds to both computable and finite. So I think you're right that to get a real analogy to ACA$_0$/RCA$_0$, we need to work in $\omega_1^{\text{ck}}$. Perhaps a better analogue to $\Pi^1_1$-CA$_0$ (on $\omega$) is not $\Sigma^0_1$-comprehension but $\Sigma^0_1$-induction, in the form of bounded $\Sigma^0_1$-comprehension.

Comment: @Denis, good idea. But when you talk about induction, you need a well ordering.  My vague ideal is that infinitary logic might be a right way to make this sense.

Comment: @Liang Yu: What I meant is, forget about induction, and instead think of bounded $\Sigma^0_1$-comprehension, which is equivalent to $\Sigma^0_1$-induction. But yes, it would be nice if there's a way to think of this as actual induction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am getting the feeling there is some slight miss-match of terminology, or perhaps application of terminology is a better way of putting it? It is true that the (lightface) $\Pi^1_1$-$CA_0$ sets of integers correspond to the meta-r.e. sets of integers, but as you say, the old meta-recursion theory lies on $\omega_1^{ck}$. So it should really be about sets of ordinals rather than integers.  However then one is really talking about $\Delta_1$-recursions over $(L_{\omega_1^{ck}},\in)$, and then the $\omega^{ck}_1$-r.e. sets are those $\Sigma_1(L_{\omega_1^{ck}},\in)$. Using a theorem of Kleene the restriction of the latter to sets of integers are indeed precisely the (lightface) $\Pi^1_1$-$CA_0$ sets of integers.

I think the link with descriptive set theory comes through *Kleene Recursion* – not much studied these days but arises as a higher type recursion theory on $\omega$ and $\omega^\omega$. Restricting it to integers, yields that the Kleene-r.e. sets are the $\Pi^1_1$ sets of integers (so again those defined in a $\Sigma_1(L_{\omega_1^{ck}},\in)$ way). Kleene recursive sets of integers correspond to those in $HYP$. Including the reals, and working at the higher type, then Kleene rec. sets corresponds to Borel and Kleene-r.e. to (boldface) co-analytic.

The `axioms', $T$, for Kleene recursion are his rules for an equational calculus for recursion on integers and reals, extending his equational calculus for the ordinary general recursive functions. (See, I think P. Hinman, *Recursion Theoretic Hierarchies*, Springer Omega Series, 1978, but also the chapter about higher type recursions in general by Dag Normann in *Turing's Legacy*, Ed. R. Downey, ASL Series in Math.Logic,vol 42, May 2104); in my chapter *Transfinite Machine Models*, in the same volume some particular facts about Kleene Recursion are summarized.)

This does not say anything about "reverse mathematics" in this context, and indeed I don't see anything resembling it here. I don't know whether Richard Shore's set-up can be made to work here.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it answers my question. One quick question, though: when you talk about Kleene recursion, are you talking about Kleene recursion relative to the equality predicate ${}^2\exists$ for reals, that is, "normal" recursion?

Comment: @Noah Yes, I am talking about that. (I am afraid I am not really saying anything about the `reverse mathematics' aspect of your Q.)